# Should I kill unfinished task in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

In Windows Forms project I have the form that runs some task on the button click like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Task(() => { DoSomeCalculations(); }).Start();
}
```

Suppose that the user close this form earlier than the task completed. Should I somehow kill unfinished task or will it finished automatically? Will application crash in this case or smth like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fire-and-forget threading very rarely works.  If it, somehow, doesn't bomb when the user presses the button a hundred times or when the window is gone then you still don't know when it safe to let your application terminate.  If you don't care about either then you don't have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cancel the tasks when closing the form, then you should add cancellation token support and call request cancel for each task. If the form is the main form you don't have to do anything - closing the UI thread will close the tasks.
If the tasks are related only to the form that is closed - then yes, you should cancel all of them.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: In you form override OnFormClosing method. Add field CancellationTokenSource tokenSource. and pass it as parameter to your method: var myTask= Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
DoSomeCalculations, tokenSource.Token);. In OnFormClosing override call     tokenSource.Cancel(); Check this link too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what should I do with the `BeginInvoke` calls?

Comment: Do you plan to update the UI when the task finished? Then you can add myTask.ContinueWith(task=>{// your code here}, taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext())

Comment: "Do you plan to update the UI when the task finished?" -- yes. "Then you can add ..." -- what does it do? Can you show me complete example, please?

Comment: It creates a TaskScheduler that wraps the SynchronizationContext returned from SynchronizationContext.Current. So when you call it will will get the synchronization context of the main thread. It means you can create Tasks that are able to access UI controls safely, simply by running them on the right scheduler.

Comment: And what is `myTask` n your example?

Comment: var myTask = new Task(() => { DoSomeCalculations(); }).ContinueWith(task=>{// your code here}, taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext()) ; myTask.Start();

Comment: And how can I pass the results of the calculations to the ContinueWith method? Only via class fields?

Comment: To use the result DoSomeCalculations should return something. Let say it returns int. So instead of Task you should use Task<int>. Then to obtain the result in ContinueWith you can use Task.Result property. Wrap the call to this in try/catch because all exceptions that happened during the task execution are thrown here.

Comment: You said that "It means you can create Tasks that are able to access UI controls safely" -- even in case when the specified form doesn't already exists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74113/discussion-between-frozenheart-and-radin-gospodinov).